# I am trying to boot an old windows xp computer without any working hard drives from my Ubuntu USB

Tags: dual-boot, usb, live-usb

I have a computer on which it's original hard drive failed. I created a Ubuntu USB running 14.04.4. When I boot to the USB, I get the installation page. I let the timer start the boot process. After a couple minutes, I get a error saying no live file system was found.

NOTE: During the Ubuntu "loading" screen there are a bunch of errors saying "line 7 /dev/sdc no medium found

Comment: Can you provide more info about your system? Laptop? Motherboard? Bios type version?

Comment: I thin your problem is related to the formatting of the USB stick and the loading of the ISO image to it. Which tool did you use to create the live?

Comment: I used both Universal USB Creator and Unetbootin. None of them worked. One question, do you need to have a working hrd drive to boot from a usb? @AndreaBorga

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that it being an old XP system that you dont have proper USB boot support from the motherboard. I have an old system like that. It has options like boot from USB FDD/CD/HDD but those dont detect modern "flash drives" for one reason or another.

What I use for this is the Plop Boot Manager burnt on to a CD which will load in just about anything. Since it is a CD.

https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html

Answer (score -1):

Try hiting pause for 2-5 minutes during startup, before it boots.
I've heard some new drives have some problems on checking in for boot.

Considering you have done everything right for creating the USB stick with ubuntu.

In case you don't know it is not just DD the iso to the usb stick.
there is a nice usb creator that comes with ubuntu. (usb-creator-gtk). You'll also need the .iso file.

Perhaps your pc doesn't meet requirements for running, you could consider Lubuntu or other light version, or even Puppy.

Comment: You shouldn't base answers to things "you have heard".  I really doubt that hitting a key for 2-5 minutes can possibly fix a problem with a computer...